# Tag synonyms: astral-plane, supplementary

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The tag [astral-plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astral-plane) is commonly used to refer to [supplementary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supplementary) planes. The latter seems to be the official term.